# Difference between 'three time' and 'three times'

Tags: nouns

> He is a [**three time**] member of lok sabha.
>
> He is a [**three times**] member of lok sabha.

What is the difference between above two?

Answer (score 3):

The correct one would be without 's.' Why? Because it then serves as an adjective. Compare:

> He is **a** three-***year***-old boy.

And,

> He is three ***years*** older to her.

So, if you want to talk about a *person,* use adjective.

> He's *a* *three-time* member of Lok Sabha [sic].

Note that we have to use the indefinite article in that case.

Comment: +1 And take note of the hyphenation when using compound adjectives.

Comment: And, to continue your analogy, we could also say, "He has been a member of Lok Sabha three times." In that case, the word _times_ goes plural.

Comment: @JasonBassford seconding your note about the hyphen.  Some native English speakers get this wrong!